# Can't install AMD drivers

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics

I've installed Ubuntu and had nothing but problems so far. First off, my secondary monitor resolution is way off and I can't choose the correct resolution. I decided to install the proprietary drive from AMD, but both options for it under Addition Drivers don't do anything, and Catalyst Control still won't work under the fglrx options.

I've tried downloading from the AMD website, from the official repositories, through additional drivers, but nothing works.

As a last note, Ubuntu thinks the graphics are `Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 256 bits)` from `VMware`. I am not running this in a VM, and my graphics card is an AMD R9 290.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Ubuntu is not recognizing your graphics card - I have had similar issues.  Your graphics performance will be poor as the CPU is being asked to render all of the graphics.  I was able to get my system running well using the oibaf graphics drivers, available at https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers

Comment: @CharlesGreen Thanks for the reply. Eventually I just ended up reinstalling Ubuntu, switching it to proprietary drivers through the Additional Drivers menu and it works. Hope this helps someone else in the future, though!